# Why do these array of pointers cause a crash a runtime?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

I was wondering if im doing anything wrong in these array of pointers? I have done my codes, but can't really figure out why it crashes at run time.
I am guessing its in my process that gets it crashed.

Here is the code
Functions

```
#include "flightInfo.h"

int getFromFileToArray(fstream& flight, char FILE[], FLIGHTInfo *AllFlight[])
{
    flight.open (FILE,ios::in);

if(!flight)
{
    cout << "File opened for reading failed" << endl;
    exit (-1);
}

cout << "File Found and is opened for reading." << endl;

int i = 0;

char flightType;

while (flight >> flightType)
{
    AllFlight[i] = new FLIGHTInfo;
    switch(flightType)
    {
        case 'A':
            AllFlight[i]->flightT = 'A';
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->FLIGHT;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->destination;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->TIME;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->terminal;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->gate;
            break;
        case 'D':
            AllFlight[i]->flightT = 'D';
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->FLIGHT;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->destination;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->TIME;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->terminal;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->gate;
            flight >> AllFlight[i]->chkInCounter;
            break;
    }
    i++;
    flight.clear();
    flight.ignore(100,'\n');
}
flight.close();
}
```

I had been at it for a few days now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry and where can i find that? im new to coding sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: yup i just saw it. im sorry for having a bad title. thanks for helping me out :) really appreciate it!

Comment: erm so should i be going to code review? but it crashes so i kinda thought here would be a good choice. sorry guys :(

Comment: So, where does your debugger say the program is crashing at? Also, to keep things clean, delete the previous comments, as those are no longer relevant.

Comment: No, do not bring broken code to Code Review.

Comment: It just crashes silently or has some error code? My hint is for you to adapt it to use std::vector instead of pointers. Really, it will save you from lots of headaches.

Comment: sorry for asking but so i bring codes that work there and ask if its good? and ask for any improvements i can do on it am i right?

Comment: At Code Review, you post working code and we will point out flaws you missed and improvements that could be make.  Do not post code there unless it is working to the best of your knowledge.  Also, you should post the entire project, or a specific section of your code if the full code is too much.

Comment: it complies and runs fine then all of a sudden it just says the program has stopped working then force closes it.
im kinda learning pointers as i would be doing pointers next sem and would like to understand it before i do it and get alot of problems trying to complete my assignments

Answer (score 4):

Your code is subject to undefined behavior. You don't return anything from `getFromFileToArray` and yet you are using:

```
int size = getFromFileToArray(flight,"infile.txt",AllFlight);
```

If you add the following line to `getFromFileToArray` just before the end of the function, your program might work.

```
return i;
```

Comment: it did! omg now i just feel so dumb... always worrying is it my pointer that failed and failed to realise its a simple problem of me forgetting to return my size from the function. Thanks alot!

Comment: @DeathbeByUs someone downvoted R Sahu's answr (you can see the vote counts by clicking on the current score) so he was asking for that voter to explain the downvote

Comment: ahhh i see! but he aint replying? do people do it for fun?

Comment: @DeathbeByUs, some users think the reason for the downvote is abvious. Most users that downvote leave a note explaining why they downvoted. Are there some that do it for fun? Probably.

Comment: well it doesnt really help if they just down vote it and not explain. hmmm. but those that do it for fun is just ......

Comment: @RSahu I don't think it was downvoting for fun. It was probably because you are answering a question which falls into the off topic category. Then again i'm not the downvoter so who knows

Comment: @AndreasMüller, I believe you are right. It will be so much better if downvoters explained the reason for downvoting.

Comment: @RSahu did that before. people go and randomly downvote your answers/questions, potentially lowering the chance of people finding a good answer. too much of a bother to let someone know that it was you who downvoted. i suppose that's the reason for some others too

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

Minor issues that don't cause your crash:

- `srand(time(NULL))` should be used only once, usually when the program starts.
- `rand()%1-30` is always -30.
- `ProcessTheArray`sorts the array `size` times. This seems unnecessary.

Major issues that may cause your crash:

- You don't return a value from `getFromFileToArray`. Your compiler should have warned you about this.
- You never initialise the `status` field.
- You got the spelling of "strcpy" wrong in quite a few places.

Comment: noted.
thanks for your answer. i wanted to do strcpy. but ended up typing strcmp. 
however what do u mean i didnt initialise the status field?